# Is there at least one prime between $n \times 100$ and $(n \times 100) + 100$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there at least one prime between the number $n \times 100$ and $(n \times 100) + 100$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that can be $0$ ?

*Question originally formulated by one of my friends.*

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376942/intervals-that-are-free-of-primes/377133#377133

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example none of the numbers between $200!+100$ and $200!+200$ can be prime, because $200!+k$ is divisible by $k$ when $2\le k\le 200$.

So a concrete counterexample would be $n=\frac{200!}{100}+1$.

---

For a smaller counterexample one could let $100n$ be the product of all primes up to 109, times 3, plus 10. That gives an $n$ with "only" $43$ digits.

---

Heuristically, based on the prime number theorem, one would expect counterexamples to start showing up as early as for $n$ in the mid-thousands. The "probability" that a random $n$ works is roughly  $(1-\frac{1}{\ln(100n)})^{100}$, and at $n=4000$ this is more than $1/4000$.

An exhaustive search, however, shows that **the smallest counterexample is *n*=16,718**. That's not *too* far from the above heuristic estimate, considering how crude it is.

Answer (score 9):

No.

Consider $n=99!$. $100n = 100!$ is composite, and $100!+1$ is divisible by $101$ (Wilson's theorem) and so is composite. $100n+i$ is divisible by $i$ for $2\leq i \leq 100$.

Comment: See also Henning's answer for a larger, but more elementary counterexample that does not require Wilson's theorem.

Comment: So this depends on the lucky shot that $101$ is prime. So if you want interval sizes that always contain a prime, look for (at minimum) something which isn't one less than a prime.

Answer (score 2):

```
     4652400 = 2^4 * 3 * 5^2 * 3877
     4652401 = 13^2 * 27529
     4652402 = 2 * 401 * 5801
     4652403 = 3 * 7^2 * 31649
     4652404 = 2^2 * 619 * 1879
     4652405 = 5 * 930481
     4652406 = 2 * 3^2 * 11 * 23497
     4652407 = 17 * 103 * 2657
     4652408 = 2^3 * 581551
     4652409 = 3 * 61 * 25423
     4652410 = 2 * 5 * 7 * 66463
     4652411 = 97 * 47963
     4652412 = 2^2 * 3 * 29^2 * 461
     4652413 = 67 * 69439
     4652414 = 2 * 13 * 178939
     4652415 = 3^2 * 5 * 103387
     4652416 = 2^7 * 19 * 1913
     4652417 = 7 * 11 * 23 * 37 * 71
     4652418 = 2 * 3 * 31 * 25013
     4652419 = 823 * 5653
     4652420 = 2^2 * 5 * 232621
     4652421 = 3 * 199 * 7793
     4652422 = 2 * 2326211
     4652423 = 1567 * 2969
     4652424 = 2^3 * 3^3 * 7 * 17 * 181
     4652425 = 5^2 * 186097
     4652426 = 2 * 2326213
     4652427 = 3 * 13 * 119293
     4652428 = 2^2 * 11 * 43 * 2459
     4652429 = 373 * 12473
     4652430 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 155081
     4652431 = 7 * 664633
     4652432 = 2^4 * 313 * 929
     4652433 = 3^2 * 599 * 863
     4652434 = 2 * 41 * 56737
     4652435 = 5 * 19 * 48973
     4652436 = 2^2 * 3 * 47 * 73 * 113
     4652437 = 1583 * 2939
     4652438 = 2 * 7 * 332317
     4652439 = 3 * 11 * 140983
     4652440 = 2^3 * 5 * 13 * 23 * 389
     4652441 = 17 * 29 * 9437
     4652442 = 2 * 3^2 * 258469
     4652443 = 397 * 11719
     4652444 = 2^2 * 1163111
     4652445 = 3 * 5 * 7 * 59 * 751
     4652446 = 2 * 53 * 43891
     4652447 = 109 * 42683
     4652448 = 2^5 * 3 * 48463
     4652449 = 31 * 223 * 673
     4652450 = 2 * 5^2 * 11^2 * 769
     4652451 = 3^3 * 172313
     4652452 = 2^2 * 7^3 * 3391
     4652453 = 13 * 167 * 2143
     4652454 = 2 * 3 * 19 * 37 * 1103
     4652455 = 5 * 930491
     4652456 = 2^3 * 581557
     4652457 = 3 * 1550819
     4652458 = 2 * 17 * 193 * 709
     4652459 = 7 * 367 * 1811
     4652460 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5 * 25847
     4652461 = 11 * 151 * 2801
     4652462 = 2 * 1327 * 1753
     4652463 = 3 * 23 * 67427
     4652464 = 2^4 * 101 * 2879
     4652465 = 5 * 131 * 7103
     4652466 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 13 * 8521
     4652467 = 107 * 43481
     4652468 = 2^2 * 79 * 14723
     4652469 = 3^2 * 139 * 3719
     4652470 = 2 * 5 * 29 * 61 * 263
     4652471 = 43 * 257 * 421
     4652472 = 2^3 * 3 * 11 * 17623
     4652473 = 7 * 19 * 34981
     4652474 = 2 * 977 * 2381
     4652475 = 3 * 5^2 * 17 * 41 * 89
     4652476 = 2^2 * 1163119
     4652477 = 911 * 5107
     4652478 = 2 * 3^6 * 3191
     4652479 = 13 * 357883
     4652480 = 2^6 * 5 * 7 * 31 * 67
     4652481 = 3 * 1550827
     4652482 = 2 * 83 * 28027
     4652483 = 11 * 47 * 8999
     4652484 = 2^2 * 3 * 387707
     4652485 = 5 * 877 * 1061
     4652486 = 2 * 23 * 101141
     4652487 = 3^2 * 7 * 73849
     4652488 = 2^3 * 71 * 8191
     4652489 = 173 * 26893
     4652490 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 155083
     4652491 = 37 * 125743
     4652492 = 2^2 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 277
     4652493 = 3 * 1550831
     4652494 = 2 * 7 * 11 * 30211
     4652495 = 5 * 930499
     4652496 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 32309
     4652497 = 2029 * 2293
     4652498 = 2 * 2326249
     4652499 = 3 * 29 * 53 * 1009
     4652500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 1861
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Awesome as usual.

Comment: You use Linux! Awesome!

Comment: @Adobe, yes, C++ with STL, and, for Pell equations, GMP, as some kinds of numbers stay small (the "digits" or "quotients") but the values of $x,y$ in $x^2 - n y^2 = m$ can become huge. Meanwhile, see the table with the first 75 maximal prime gaps in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results which is how I knew 4652400 would work, after which I did an exhaustive search and repeated Henning's  find of the first failure. In any case, read about prime gaps.

Comment: Thank you so much @WillJagy

Comment: b.t.w: I have a question, is there a generalization of this? for let's say n1000 and n1000+1000, n10.000 and n10.000 + 10.000 ... and so on?

Comment: @Adobe, a relatively early counterexample for your 1000 problem begins with 80873624627235000 and has all composite numbers up to 80873624627236000. There will always be counterexamples for these, finding the **earliest** counterexample for one of them becomes arduous. Compare this information from the Prime Gaps table, gap = 1220, beginning prime = 80873624627234849. That is, the next prime is 80873624627236069.

Answer (score 2):

Earliest failure:

```
 1671800 = 2^3 * 5^2 * 13 * 643
 1671801 = 3 * 23 * 24229
 1671802 = 2 * 11 * 75991
 1671803 = 7 * 238829
 1671804 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 46439
 1671805 = 5 * 239 * 1399
 1671806 = 2 * 769 * 1087
 1671807 = 3 * 557269
 1671808 = 2^7 * 37 * 353
 1671809 = 599 * 2791
 1671810 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 19 * 419
 1671811 = 137 * 12203
 1671812 = 2^2 * 417953
 1671813 = 3^3 * 11 * 13 * 433
 1671814 = 2 * 17 * 49171
 1671815 = 5 * 334363
 1671816 = 2^3 * 3 * 41 * 1699
 1671817 = 7 * 241 * 991
 1671818 = 2 * 835909
 1671819 = 3 * 557273
 1671820 = 2^2 * 5 * 83591
 1671821 = 29 * 57649
 1671822 = 2 * 3^2 * 131 * 709
 1671823 = 191 * 8753
 1671824 = 2^4 * 7 * 11 * 23 * 59
 1671825 = 3 * 5^2 * 22291
 1671826 = 2 * 13 * 64301
 1671827 = 61 * 27407
 1671828 = 2^2 * 3 * 127 * 1097
 1671829 = 19 * 87991
 1671830 = 2 * 5 * 31 * 5393
 1671831 = 3^2 * 7^2 * 17 * 223
 1671832 = 2^3 * 53 * 3943
 1671833 = 1289 * 1297
 1671834 = 2 * 3 * 278639
 1671835 = 5 * 11 * 113 * 269
 1671836 = 2^2 * 417959
 1671837 = 3 * 47 * 71 * 167
 1671838 = 2 * 7 * 119417
 1671839 = 13 * 128603
 1671840 = 2^5 * 3^5 * 5 * 43
 1671841 = 1223 * 1367
 1671842 = 2 * 109 * 7669
 1671843 = 3 * 557281
 1671844 = 2^2 * 417961
 1671845 = 5 * 7 * 37 * 1291
 1671846 = 2 * 3 * 11 * 73 * 347
 1671847 = 23 * 72689
 1671848 = 2^3 * 17 * 19 * 647
 1671849 = 3^2 * 431^2
 1671850 = 2 * 5^2 * 29 * 1153
 1671851 = 67 * 24953
 1671852 = 2^2 * 3 * 7 * 13 * 1531
 1671853 = 101 * 16553
 1671854 = 2 * 835927
 1671855 = 3 * 5 * 227 * 491
 1671856 = 2^4 * 104491
 1671857 = 11^2 * 41 * 337
 1671858 = 2 * 3^2 * 293 * 317
 1671859 = 7 * 238837
 1671860 = 2^2 * 5 * 179 * 467
 1671861 = 3 * 31 * 17977
 1671862 = 2 * 835931
 1671863 = 359 * 4657
 1671864 = 2^3 * 3 * 69661
 1671865 = 5 * 13 * 17^2 * 89
 1671866 = 2 * 7 * 119419
 1671867 = 3^3 * 19 * 3259
 1671868 = 2^2 * 11 * 37997
 1671869 = 83 * 20143
 1671870 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 23 * 2423
 1671871 = 487 * 3433
 1671872 = 2^6 * 151 * 173
 1671873 = 3 * 7 * 79613
 1671874 = 2 * 835937
 1671875 = 5^6 * 107
 1671876 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 46441
 1671877 = 79 * 21163
 1671878 = 2 * 13 * 64303
 1671879 = 3 * 11 * 29 * 1747
 1671880 = 2^3 * 5 * 7^2 * 853
 1671881 = 331 * 5051
 1671882 = 2 * 3 * 17 * 37 * 443
 1671883 = 43 * 59 * 659
 1671884 = 2^2 * 47 * 8893
 1671885 = 3^2 * 5 * 53 * 701
 1671886 = 2 * 19 * 43997
 1671887 = 7 * 238841
 1671888 = 2^4 * 3 * 61 * 571
 1671889 = 521 * 3209
 1671890 = 2 * 5 * 11 * 15199
 1671891 = 3 * 13 * 163 * 263
 1671892 = 2^2 * 31 * 97 * 139
 1671893 = 23 * 157 * 463
 1671894 = 2 * 3^3 * 7 * 4423
 1671895 = 5 * 334379
 1671896 = 2^3 * 103 * 2029
 1671897 = 3 * 181 * 3079
 1671898 = 2 * 41 * 20389
 1671899 = 17 * 98347
 1671900 = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 * 5573
```

Comment: I see, Henning indicated the first failure late in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a generalization of some of the other answers, there are arbitrarily long sequences of composites: Namely, consider the numbers $N! + 2, N! + 3, N! + 4, ..., N!+N$ which has length $N - 1$.